# How to design overlaying views in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

My App is using `Angular` and `UI-router`. There are two pages, the **first page** (state : "book") shows the categories and book list. The book item is clicked, the page will be switch to the **book detail**(state: "bookDetail").

However, when I switch back to book list, it reload the view and do not preserve the scroll and all other stuff.

In my opinion, the relation of **book list** and **book detail** is more like the relation of content and modal, not the parallel views. But I find  it is hard to understand the modal in `ui-router` state system, because a modal is not navigating you to a specific view, rather just overlaying it.

Any solution to operating the views as a modal and routerizing it with `state`?

```
$stateProvider.when('bookList',{
    url : '/bookList',
    ...
}).when('bookList.bookDetail',{
    url : '/bookDetail/{bookid}'
}).when('bookList.buyBook',{
    url : '/bookDetail/{bookid}'
    ...
})
```

As above, the child views should overlay the parent view, and is removed when the url goes back.